# Use of ! and chomp method in ruby

Tags: ruby

I am a newbie to ruby. While I try to read a line without newline character I learn about chomp method. This method is used to remove \n from the end of the string. So, I tried the following scenario.

Program:

```
arr = Array.new;

while true
    char = gets     // Read line from input
    if char == nil      // If EOF reach then break  
        break
    end
    char.chomp      // Try to remove \n at the end of string
    arr << char     // Append the line into array
end

p arr           // print the array
```

Output:

```
$ ruby Array.rb 
abc
def
["abc\n", "def\n"]
$
```

But it doesn't remove newline at the end of the string. But if '!' is provided at the end of chomp (char.chomp!), it worked properly. So
what is the need of '!' and why it is used ? what ! stands for ?

Comment: Use `#`s for comments in Ruby.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As the [good documentation says](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-chomp), chomp returns a new string with newline removed, while chomp! modifies the string itself.

So, `char.chomp      // Try to remove \n at the end of string` returns a new string, but you are not assigning that new string with newline removed to any variable.

Here are possible fixes:

```
char.chomp!      // Try to remove \n at the end of string
arr << char     // Append the line into array
```

or

```
str = char.chomp      // Try to remove \n at the end of string
arr << str     // Append the line into array
```

or

```
arr << char.chomp     // Append the line into array
```

Comment: So, If I use ! at the end of the method, then the operation takes on the object itself. Is it right?

Comment: In this specific case, yes.

Comment: @mrg: No. It has absolutely nothing whatsoever to do with the `!`. Ruby doesn't care what the methods are called. They could be called `strip_whitespace` and `strip_whitespace_destructive`. They happen to be called `chomp` and `chomp!`, but they could just as well be called `foo` and `bar`.

Comment: @Zabba I think `comp` is a typo  in your last code example.

Comment: Whaaaat! Ruby comped up the `h` :) (yes, it was a typo :)

Comment: You could also just do `while true`; `char = gets.chomp` that way you don't have to just through any hoops later on.

Answer (score 0):

When you do this `char.chomp` then the output will not have `\n` characters but the string inside `char` will remain unchanged, in ruby `!` is a convention that is used after a method to change the object itself, this does not mean that just adding `!` to your method will change that object, but it is just a convention that is followed in method definitions, so if you do `char.chomp!`, it will change the value of char itself, that is why you see the correct result. What you could do here is just `arr << char.chomp`, this will add the the value without `\n` to your array and also it will not change the actual object.

Comment: `in ruby ! is used after a method to change the object itself` => this is not correct actually. The `!` is simply a character you can use in a method name. While the common convention is that using the `!` denotes a destructive or in-place modification of an object, it is not always the case. Jjust using `!` does not mean it always modifies the object.

Comment: Yes that is true, what I meant was that it is a convention that is followed in most of the methods, I have edited my response.

Answer (score -1):

The methods that end in **!** indicate that the method will modify the object it's called on. Ruby calls these "dangerous methods" because they change state that someone else might have a reference to.

```
   arr = Array.new;

    while true
        char = gets     
        if char == nil      
            break
        end

        char.chomp      
        puts char

   // result = 'your string/n' (The object reference hasn't got changed.)

    char2 = char.chomp

    puts char2

   // result = 'your string' (The variable changed but not the object reference)

    char.chomp!

    puts char

  //  result = 'your string' (The object reference chaned)

    Now you can either do,

    arr << char     // Append the line into array

    or,

    arr << char2    
    end

    p arr           // print the array
```

They both give you the same result.

Comment: whats the reason to vote down, any mistake you found in it?